# Center a dynamic width, fixed position object with an underline

Tags: html, css, css-position

For some reason I am stumped over such a simple thing.

How can I center align a fixed position object with a bottom border that will vary in width?

The problem I have now is that it works only with a 100% width object.

I could do this easily with a fixed width div, or with javascript, but is there a css-only solution to this?

http://jsbin.com/uvaron/2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `display: inline-block;` on `#title p`.

[**demo**](http://jsbin.com/uvaron/4/edit)

Comment: Utterly perfect and simple, thankyou! Interesting, I had never heard of 'inline-block'. Good to know and look into.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with just CSS.  If you set your fixed element to have a `left: 50%` and `margin-left: -[half the width of your element]` it will center even on resize.

Here's a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/scrimothy/hWKgv/)

Comment: Sorry, I realize I neglected the "dynamic width" aspect of your question.